# How to change every other blank space to tab in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Let say I have a text like this

```
> Name
> 
> Peak
>
> Surname
>
> Sornpaisarn
```

But I want the whole document to be written like this

```
Name    Peak
Surname Sornpaisarn
```

So for the odd blank space, I want to change to tab. For the even blank space I want to delete it. Are there anything in vs code that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the final line is just `>`, so that the final key-space-value-space chunk is the same as the others
- Make a backup copy of your page. If the edit ruins it, you can replace it and try something else
- Choose "Replace" from the Edit menu
- in the find/replace dialog, click the little `.*` box to turn on regular expressions
- in the top (find) box, enter `>\s([^\n]+)\n>\n>\s([^\n]+)\n>`
- in the bottom (replace with) box, enter `$1\t$2`
- click in front of the first character in the file so you'll start the conversion there
- click the little "replace" or "replace all" buttons (little `b -> c` icons to the right of the "replace with" text)